# JSPs opening in black-white in Kepler (Eclipse Standard 4.3)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have `Eclipse Standard 4.3 (Kepler)` installed, but the jsp pages are opening in black and white. I guess that I haven't downloaded the EE version, that's why its the case. What can I do now ? The xml files are opening in coloured format.

I searched for jsp plugins, but the editors that came up in the options didn't have '`Install`' option beside them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the FAQs of Eclipse Kepler [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#Does_the_WTP_include_a_visual_JSP_editor.3F). Eclipse WTP includes JSP editor.

**UPDATE:**

You can download web tools [From Here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/)

You install [WTP tools for eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and [start developing servlets/JSPs from eclipse](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~hhou/eclipse_installation.html)

Comment: Yes.. but without the wtp, can I directly get jsp editor on the eclipse

Comment: You are probably just getting the file opened in the basic text editor.

Comment: You must have webtools installed in your eclipse to develop web modules like jsp, HTML etc.. Check out this http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~hhou/eclipse_installation.html

Answer (score 7):

This problem can be solved by

1. Right Click on JSP and open with JSP Editor
2. We have to install the JSP Editor from MENU BAR - HELP - INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE - WORK WITH (Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler) - THEN SELECT (Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development) FROM LIST.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on jsp -> Open With -> JSP Editor

Comment: install JSF Tools - Web Page Editor